# Find minimum steps to convert all elements to zero

Tags: algorithm

> You are given an array of positive integers of size N. You can choose any positive number x such that x<=max(Array) and subtract it from all elements of the array greater than and equal to x.
> This operation has a cost A[i]-x for A[i]>=x. The total cost for a particular step is the
> sum(A[i]-x). A step is only valid if the sum(A[i]-x) is less than or equal to a given number K.
> For all the valid steps find the minimum number of steps to make all elements of the array zero.
>
> 0<=i<10^5
> 0<=x<=10^5
> 0<k<10^5

Can anybody help me with any approach? DP will not work due to high constraints.

Comment: Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 I think I made myself very clear while writing the question. What I tried and why that can not be a good approach so there is no point in showing the wrong approach and having a discussion around it. Also, I am not asking for straight answers and code, this is not an assignment. I am asking for a better approach and hints on how to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: How is this related to digital signature algorithm (DSA)?

Comment: May I ask if there is a real-world problem where this pops up?

Comment: @Vroomfondel sorry but the answers I got here are not in the way I think the problem should be solved. Especially in a coding round, I don't think this sol will go.

Comment: Still no real answer to this interesting problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just some general exploratory thoughts.

First, there should be a constraint on `N`.  If `N` is 3, this is much easier than if it is 100.  The naive brute force approach is going to be `O(k^N)`

Next, you are right that DP will not work with these constraints.

For a greedy approach, I would want to minimize the number of distinct non-zero values, and not maximize how much I took.  Our worst case approach is take out the largest each time, for `N` steps.  If you can get 2 pairs of entries to both match, then that shortened our approach.

The obvious thing to try if you can is an [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  However that requires a LOWER bound (not upper).  The best naive lower bound that I can see is `ceil(log_2(count_distinct_values))`.  Unless you're incredibly lucky and the problem can be solved that quickly, this is unlikely to narrow your search enough to be helpful.

I'm curious what trick makes this problem actually doable.

---

I do have an idea.  But it is going to take some thought to make it work.  Naively we want to take each choice for `x` and explore the paths that way.  And this is a problem because there are `10^5` choices for `x`.  After 2 choices we have a problem, and after 3 we are definitely not going to be able to do it.

BUT instead consider the possible orders of the array elements (with ties both possible and encouraged) and the resulting inequalities on the range of choices that could have been made.  And now instead of having to store a `10^5` choices of `x` we only need store the distinct orderings we get, and what inequalities there are on the range of choices that get us there.  As long as `N < 10`, the [number of weak orderings](https://oeis.org/A000670) is something that we can deal with if we're clever.

It would take a bunch of work to flesh out this idea though.

Comment: I was thinking if one could work on the histogram instead of the original array?

Comment: Plus a spectral analysis to determine favorable cuts in the histogram?

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally wrong, and if so, please tell me and I'm going to delete my thoughts: maybe there is an opportunity if we translate the problem into another form?

You are given an array A of positive integers of size N.

> Calculate the histogram H of this array.
>
> The highest populated slot of this histogram has index `m` ( `== max(A)`).
>
> Find the shortest sequence of selections of `x` for:
>
> - Select an index `x <= m` which satisfies `sum(H[i]*(i-x)) <= K` for `i = x+1 .. m` (search for suitable `x` starts from `m` down)
> - Add `H[x .. m]` to `H[0 .. m-x]`
> - Set the new `m` as the highest populated index in `H[0 .. x-1]` (we ignore everything from `H[x]` up)
> - Repeat until `m == 0`

If there is only a "good" but not optimal solution sought for, I could imagine that some kind of spectral analysis of `H` could hint towards favorable `x` selections so that maxima in the histogram pile upon other maxima in the reduction step.